# MongoDB Geo-Spatial Query for Coordinates in an Array

Tags: swift, mongodb, nosql, geolocation

My app chooses locations of chain restaurants based off of users current location. Ideally in my Mongo DB I want to have a document for each retailer and then an array of addresses (one for each physical location). However, based off of my understanding of Mongo geo-spatial query documentation, it seems like it only works on a per-document-basis (must be used as the first stage of an aggregate pipeline), and thus cannot be used on an array of locations within a set of documents?

This creates an issue as when my app scales I will have to add a single document entry for EVERY retail location so the geo-spatial query can acknowledge it, which doesn't seem realistic.

Does anyone here know of a workaround with the query, or have any ideas on how I can structure my DB documents to alleviate this issue?